# Looping functoid, Mapping

Tags: xml, mapping, schema, biztalk

I've used two input schemas i.e. SCHEMA1 and GUID and output schema is also the SCHEMA1.
First input schema is normal xml which includes Name, address and RefID as the elements and second input schema includes the GUID's which is hard coded in the message assignment box in orchestration.
I want to use both the input schema to get the output schema which includes name, address, RefID and GUID in it.

I've used looping functoid and getting the result but GUID is not coming along with them.
Also i've tried with index functoid but only the single GUID is coming in all the fields.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your map?

Comment: @DanField Also I have the images but it is not allowing me to post the images. Some error is coming saying u must have atleast 10 reputation to post the images. what to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your map, but it seems likely that this would be easier to do with a helper library.  Have a C# class that has a list (containing your GUIDs) and a method that takes an index (which cold be passed from the iteration functoid) and returns the respective GUID from the list.  You could set the GUIDs in the orchestration and then call the method fro ma scripting functoid.

Comment: I've done with scripting functoid but the major task is to complete it with looping functoid.

Comment: Also I have the images but it is not allowing me to post the images. Some error is coming saying u must have atleast 10 reputation to post the images. what to do?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you can't post images yet.  You can still use the looping functoid - the idea with the scripting functoid would be to avoid using some kind fo complex table looping monstrosity.